# supabase edge-function code 504 with no logs

Tags: javascript, networking, backend, supabase

My edge function had been working perfectly.
When it runs it usually begins with a log saying "booted".

I can usually run it using the sql query:

```
SELECT
  net.http_post(
  url:='https://something.supabase.co/functions/v1/something',
  headers:='{"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "something"}'::jsonb
  ) as request_id;
```

All of a sudden, today it just stopped working. Running the sql query returns a request_id but the edge function never runs, there are no invocations and there are no logs.

I tried using curl which runs for 60 seconds then reports a 504 Gateway Timeout. When using curl, supabase does record the invocation as a 504 error, but it doesn't record any logs.

In addition there are usually valid values for these two parameters in the invocation response metadata headers.

```
      "x_sb_edge_region": null,
      "x_served_by": null
```

But now they are reporting null. It seems like the function is never reaching the edge servers.

I thought it could be quota limit, but I checked it in the Settings > Subscription > Billing Breakdown tab and nothing is anywhere near the limit.

The contents of the function are irrelevant. I made a new function with the default "Hello from Functions!" code, and it won't run either. Only reports a 504 code.

This seems to be an intended feature, but there is no documentation on the code 504 and I couldn't find any other questions about it.

Comment: I don't know if it's related, but there is a user with similar error who said the error went away after upgrading the libraries in the code base to the latest version. https://www.reddit.com/r/Supabase/comments/160qmh6/edge_function_working_locally_but_giving_504_when/

Comment: Actually it turned out Supabase was just down for a few hours, and none of their edge functions were working for that time period.